# Cost Per Result in Facebook Ads api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get 'Results', 'Result Rate' and 'Cost Per Result' metric in Facebook Ads API.

Currently I fetch objectives for campaigns and get the data for results, result rate metrics based on the objective of campaign.

But when the objective for campaigns is "Conversion", we send actions as field,get both offsite_conversions and offsite_conversion:custom:134355662(some custom conversion name). Currently we are fetching only offsite_conversions(which implies all website conversions)

So my question is How do we know which campaign has which custom conversion associated, so that we could map that custom conversion conversions